# how to show toast above overlay library

Tags: lightning-aura-components

currently i am using toast to show validation coming from server side but as my component shows up in popup(overlay library) toast is not showing above the popup instead it shows below the popup. any one have idea regarding this?

**Component Code :**

```
<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
```

**JS controller code**

```
let toastParams = {title: "Error",
                   message: "Unknown error", // Default error message
                   type: "error",
                   mode: 'dismissible'
};
toastParams.message  = errors[0].pageErrors[0].message;
let toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
toastEvent.setParams(toastParams);
toastEvent.fire();
```

Comment: Better UX would be to display the error message in an inline above form according to SLDS guidelines, lightning:overlayLibrary doesn't supports toast messages, it goes behind dialog.